# Selecionar elementos pares em alinhamento

Tags: css

Estou tentando selecionar os elementos que estão em um nível par de aninhamento:

```html
<div>
   A
   <div>
      B
      <div>
         C
         <div>
            D
            <div>
               E
               <div>
                  F
                   <div>
                    G
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Eu estou tentando fazer isso com o seguinte código:

```css
div, div div div, div div div div div {
        background: red;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    div div, div div div div {
        background: blue;
    }
```

[image: Fica assim o resultado]

O problema disso é que se eu tiver mil divs aninhadas eu preciso fazer um seletor css com 1000 também

Comment: Coloque um `class` nas divs que vc quer azul: `class="azul"` e use vermelho nas divs: `div { background-color: red; }`. E adicione no CSS a classe `.azul { background-color: blue; }`.

Comment: Minha dúvida é se teria como fazer sem precisar colocar classe nas divs, algum seletor ou uma forma de organizar os seletores, algo como o  :nth-child(2n), só que para selecionar as divs que estão no aninhamento par